# Can we replace Default SharePoint Search Web Part by any custom web part

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I am wondering if I can can replace the default SharePoint Search Web Part by any Custom Search Web Part by setting some priority or Sequence ID to the Custom Web Part.

Any kind of help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Search Web Part is not the search box at the top of SharePoint pages, those are a usercontrol defined in the MasterPage of your site. To change that box you need to edit your masterpage and edit/remove the usercontrol with your own.

The basic masterpage for sharepoint is located at _/catalogs/masterpages/default.master

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, we need to use delegate mechanism to replace that user control. 

I have created a separate site template with all the custom web parts for our Search. But I am not sure how to support the scopes in the site template.

I am getting confused by the post below:
http://espwebparts.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=45480

Here they are telling that they have used "k" parameter from URL. But I wonder why do they have to use that if they are doing a separate Site Template.

Sorry if my question was wrong

Thanks

Carol

Comment: I believe the FAST WP only gets different result pages, so the search box is the same, the default box sends a querytring parameter called 'k' for the keyword and another called 's' for the scopes. Maybe you can use the default search mechanic and have your custom results page or something like that.

Comment: Thank You very much for your help.

I still have a doubt if I am not wrong, will it really matter using Default Search Box web part or any other Custom Web Part.

Because any ways FAST is not redirecting default Search from every site. They are just creating a complete separate template which doesn't need to have the same Search Box as sharePoint's.

Thanks

Carol

Comment: I guess they just the similar mechanic to simplify customization